# Target class [PersonTableSeeder] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run `php artisan db:seed`
but getting this error same running this command `php artisan db:seed --class=PersonTableSeeder`:

```
Target class [PersonTableSeeder] does not exist.
database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:14
          Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call("PersonTableSeeder")
    
          +24 vendor frames
          34  artisan:37
          Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

P.S Everybody says to run `composer dump-autoload` but it doesn't help me to solve this issue.
I also tried these commands with no result:

```
    php artisan optimize
    php artisan clear:cache
    composer clearcache
    composer dump-autoload
```

Also I made sure that both DatabaseSeeder and PersonTableSeeder files are in the same folder

This is my code:

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(PersonTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

PersonTableSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Person;

class PersonTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Person::class, 50)->create();
    }
}
```

PersonFactory:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Person::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
        'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'city' => $faker->city,
    ];
});
```

Comment: Not exactly familiar with Laravel, but aren't your classes supposed to be in (PSR4-like) namespaces?

Comment: @Jeto not before Laravel 8, the folders they are in are classmapped (by default)

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.9.0
Do you think it might be a reason of this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with version of Laravel as I was following an older tutorial. Tutorial was 5.8.11 version my newly created laravel was 8.9 version. After clonning github repo and intalling everything I got it working. But would like to understand why I was getting this error as downgrading laravel from 8.9 to 5.8.11 is really painful and now I am getting a weird error after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

for those who land on this page still looking for an answer, if you run
`composer dump-autoload` it'll solve your issue!

Answer (score 1):

it's simple, just do a

```
composer dump-autoload
```

it worked for me